# Simple_form doesn't display form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Hi in my rails application I am using `simple_form` gem for contact form, same contact form is rendered in two controllers. In one controller it works well and in another the form fields are not shown. While checking that by firebug this is the output

```
<form class="contact_form" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/controller/contactform" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<div class="input string required contact_form_name" style="display: none;">
<label class="string required" for="contact_form_name" style="display: none;">
<input id="contact_form_name" class="string required" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Name" name="contact_form[name]" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="input email required contact_form_email" style="display: none;">
<div class="input string required contact_form_title" style="display: none;">
<div class="input text required contact_form_message" style="display: none;">
<input class="btn btn-larger btn-danger" type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit">
</form>
```

it says `display: none`, I changed the class name in **simple_form.rb** file also, but it does not work....what to do?

Comment: which code do you wrote by using simple form? put that also here.

Comment: @Navin please add both controller's action code with views where you rendered it.

Comment: what is IT (in it shows)? also please show the view